# Can i make a http payload?

Tags: exploit, metasploit, trojan

**Hello stack exchange community**, I was wondering if i can generate a payload that connects using http . Because it will be faster and it will avoid all the problems of port forwarding and explloiting. Can i generate such payloads using metasploit?

Comment: How does the choice of protocol (HTTP) impact port forwarding?

Comment: @Arminius like botnet no need to port forwrding it's just a question of improving securty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.
You can generate metasploit HTTP/HTTPS payloads (more on this [here](https://community.rapid7.com/community/metasploit/blog/2011/06/29/meterpreter-httphttps-communication))
or you can write one from scratch.

Comment: thanks bro how we write it from scratch i know python programming language

Comment: you can ask another question for that, don't use comments, ask a new question, I'll help you out.